# Affine varieties - working with intersections and unions, and when the variety is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I was trying to understand affine varieties, and I considered something that I quickly deduced was false:

- False: If the vanishing ideal has even one irreducible generator, then the zero set is irreducible.

So I considered $I=(x,yz)\in \Bbb C[x,y,z]$.

I saw that $$V(x,yz)=V(x)\cap V(yz)=V(x)\cap(V(y)\cup V(z))= (V(x)\cap V(y))\cup (V(x)\cap V(z))$$
$$=V(x,y)\cup V(x,z)$$
Now at this step I was happy. I can see that our variety is just the $y$ and $z$ axis.

> - **Question 1**: Can I break up the variety by intersection whenever I see a comma?
> - **Question 2**: Can I break up the variety by union, whenever I see a product?

With these two, which I have used above, I can then see that $V(x,yz)=V(x^2,xz,xy,yz)$, but the ideal inside the bracket on the right, cannot generate $x$? My ideal isn't equal to its radical anymore, which it was originally?

> - **Question 3**: I suppose we can't distinguish between $V(x,yz)$ and $V(x^2,yz)$ can we?
> - **Question 4**: $V(I)$ is only irreducible, when every generator is?

For $Q4$, my thought is that if there is a single reducible generator, say $f_1$ in $I=(f_1,\cdots,f_n)$ and all $f_i$ for $i>1$ are irreducible, then by $Q1$ I have:
$$V(I) = V(f_1)\cap \cdots \cap V(f_n),$$
and say $f_1=g_1g_2$, then I have:
$$V(I) = (V(g_1)\cup V(g_2))\cap V(f_2)\cap \cdots\cap V(f_n)$$
$$= \mathbf{(}V(g_1)\cap V(f_2)\cap \cdots \cap V(f_n)\mathbf{)}\cup \mathbf{(}V(g_2)\cap V(f_2)\cap \cdots\cap V(f_n)\mathbf{)}$$
and thus we have shown $V(I)$ is reducible?

Comment: I would relate $IJ,I \cap J,V(I) \cup V(J)$ (assuming $(I,J)=(1)$) and $V(I) \cap V(J), V((I,J))$.

Comment: "If the vanishing ideal has even one irreducible generator, then the zero set is irreducible". How can you prove this is wrong ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelrazek I did in the question, $V(x,yz)$ has an irreducible generator $x$ and a reducible generator $yz$, and $V(x,yz)=V(x,y)\cup V(x,z)$.

Comment: Aha ... ok I misunderstood the statement. Thanks

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelrazek That's alright, I realize that the phrasing could be easier haha. Originally I thought it might be a true statement, and if it were true, it seems nicely phrased.

Comment: $(x,y) \cap (x,z)= ?$

Comment: @reuns $(x,xz,xy,yz)=(x,yz)$? Oh right, so above is wrong.